# Is there a way to map the uppercase Z key alone?

Tags: key-bindings

I was trying to map the Z and X keys like this:

```
nnoremap Z v"-yjv"-pkv"-pj
nnoremap X v"-ykv"-pjv"-pk
```

But, of course, the `Z` mapping didn't work because `Z` is a key that waits for another key as in the built-in commands `ZZ` and `ZQ`.

I thought on mapping these built-in commands to `<Nop>` but it also wouldn't work.

```
nnoremap ZZ <Nop>
nnoremap ZQ <Nop>
```

So, the question is:
Is there a way to map `Z`?

My current workaround involves the `CTRL` key. It looks like this:

```
nnoremap <C-Z> v"-yjv"-pkv"-pj
nnoremap <C-X> v"-ykv"-pjv"-pk
nnoremap <C-S> <C-X>
```

Having to use the `CTRL` key is not as smooth and easy to the fingers as simple uppercase letters. Here I also had to remap the `<C-X>` command to keep the `<C-A>` - `<C-X>` pair functionality alive.

By the way, these mappings just exchange one character with another one in the same column without messing with the line length, `<C-Z>` does it with the character above, whereas `<C-X>` does it with the character underneath. I'm using the small delete register `"-` as temporal storage.

Comment: I would very much advise against it, but here we go: `:h map-<nowait>`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thank you so much! It worked. The final mapping looks like this: `nnoremap <nowait> Z v"-yjv"-pkv"-pj`

Comment: @Rich I've also found out that the `'timeoutlen'` option determines how much you will have to wait before a single mapped key takes effect when there are other possible combined mappings with that key.